# Is there a way to keep keys in secure store application static for life of it?

Tags: secure-store

We are using secure store to keep key/salt for encrypting certain fields submitted from InfoPath form (like SSN). We want to ensure the key does not get refreshed or else our encrypted data will be "encrypted" one way forever. We use SP group to show plain text or decrypted when submitted form is viewed by approver

Answer (score 1):

With the secure store application, it doesn't matter if it's encryption key gets refreshed, your data won't change (other than being re-encrypted with the new SSA password).  As far as the salt/key you are storing, once it's created, set the permissions on the item in the secure store so that it no longer has any administrators.  That should prevent anyone but those with farm admin or SSA admin privileges from changing it.

Basically, once it's in the SSA, it will only be changed if a person or custom code changes it.  And, there is nothing really to prevent those with the appropriate access from changing it.